# passport bcrypt throw "Incorrect arguments"

Tags: passport.js, bcrypt, passport-local

Been working on this for a while now and can't seem to figure it out. Have looked through post I can find & stackoverflow post. Nothing has seem to work. The logged error:

```
Users/username/Sites/dev/node_modules/bcrypt-nodejs/bCrypt.js:642
    throw "Incorrect arguments";
        ^
Incorrect arguments
```

The user.js and passport.js can be seen here. http://pastebin.com/CEy6QBkP

The error is coming from this function and the compareSync

```
var isValidPassword = function(user, password){
    return bCrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);
}
```

Something to do with the hash & salt compared to req.body.password. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: heads up; using bcrypt sync function can be a very bad idea since it is designed to be intentionally slow. It will block your app for around 300ms every time it is called. Mind this.

Answer (score 5):

You can check the type of both variables to make sure both are Strings. Ran into the same issue a while back. Code below did the trick for me.. Hopefully that will help a bit.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs')

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    fullname : String,
    role: String,

})

userSchema.methods.generateHash = function(password){
  return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(10), null)
}

userSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password){
  return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password)
}

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you had previously used a social login to create the user account then most likely the user will not have a password associated to the account. So the error might be as a result of comparing a null password.

Check your user model and make this change

```
var isValidPassword = function(user, password){
if(this.password != null) {return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
} else {return false; }}
```